# QR code to open link that asks to take a picture?

Tags: ipad, camera, photo, qr-code

I'm making a quest (for iPads) and would like to use QR codes that users have to scan and then do certain tasks: The user scans the QR code, which links to a text that asks them to take a picture of a certain object and a button that opens up the camera, once the picture is taken it is saved. I was thinking of a blog, where images can get uploaded once they are taken, but they could as well be stored on the iPad. I haven't found a solution using blogs, as taking an image can't be prompted, any idea how it could be done?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to make a web application?

Answer (score 1):

Not really possible with a web app. You could have the link in your QR code point to your native app’s custom URL scheme, as in `myapp://whatever`, and then both get and upload the photo through that app, but what you’re trying to do isn’t possible through Safari.